# Need help to optimze a code for radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
    if ($('#subscribe').is(':checked')){
         $("#subNow").show();
         $('#oneTime').hide();
    }
    if ($('#one-time').is(':checked')){
       $('#oneTime').show();
       $("#subNow").hide();
    }   
});
```

The above code is to show and hide 2 div's on click of 2 radio buttons. I am new to jquery so would like to know is there a better way to write this same functionality.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code unless you have a thousand checkboxes and you only need the event bound to a few.

Comment: Add value to you radio boxes.  Then instead of check if each radio is checked.  You can just get the value `jQuery(this).val()  and use the value like this` if(value == 'onetime')jQuery('#onetime').hide()`

Answer (score 2):

If you setup the initial state, say `#subNow { display: none; }`, then just use the `.toggle()` method, no conditions check what-so-ever...

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
  $("#subNow").toggle();
  $('#oneTime').toggle();
});
```

```css
#subNow {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' name='rd' checked />1
<input type='radio' name='rd' />2
<br />
<div id="subNow">subNow</div>
<div id="oneTime">oneTime</div>
```

**Also,**

if perhaps they are followed on the markup, why not drop JS and go CSS-only??

```css
input[type="radio"]:nth-child(2):checked ~ #oneTime,
#subNow
{
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:nth-child(2):checked ~ #subNow{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type='radio' name='rd' checked />1
<input type='radio' name='rd' />2
<br />
<div id="subNow">subNow</div>
<div id="oneTime">oneTime</div>
```

Comment: I was going to reply the same +1

Comment: you can even do `$("#subNow, #oneTime).toggle();`

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the way I would do this. The only other option would be to get the value of the radio buttons, but you'd essentially be doing the same thing that you already are.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @GibboK the user basically asked if he was doing this the correct way so my answer was responding to the fact that this is indeed how it should be done. So IMO it provides a direct answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use common classes and data attributes

```js
    $(".rads").on("change", '[type="radio"]', function (e) {
        var show = $(this).data("show");
        $(".details").hide().filter(show).show();
    });
```

```css
.details {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rads">
        <input type="radio" id="x" name="rad" data-show=".foo" />
        <label for="x">A</label>
        <input type="radio" id="y" name="rad" data-show=".bar" />
        <label for="y">B</label>
    </div>
    <div class="foo details">Apple</div>
    <div class="bar details">Bacon</div>
```

There is also pure CSS solutions using the :checked selector.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any other states to worry about, you can cut the second `if` and place a `else`

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
    if ($('#subscribe').is(':checked')){
         $("#subNow").show();
         $('#oneTime').hide();
    }
    else{
       $('#oneTime').show();
       $("#subNow").hide();
    }   
});
```

You can also use [switch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)